# Can't migrate database because environments variables are not available beanstalk

Tags: django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm currently encountering quite an annoying problem with my Django server on AWS Beanstalk.

My Database and S3 storage end points, account aliases and keys all exists as env variables, so for example I would access my database like this

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': os.environ['RDS_DB_NAME'],
        'USER': os.environ['RDS_USERNAME'],
        'PASSWORD': os.environ['RDS_PASSWORD'],
        'HOST': os.environ['RDS_HOSTNAME'],
        'PORT': os.environ['RDS_PORT'],
        'OPTIONS': {
            'autocommit': True,
        },
    }
}
```

The problem arises when I need to make change to my model. I would want to be able to run migrations on Beanstalk after every update, so i have this in my ebextensions config file.

```
container_commands:
  01_migrate:
    command: 'source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && django-admin.py makemigrations'
    command: 'source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && django-admin.py migrate'
    leader_only: true
```

But this doesn't work, as somehow I get the error that the environment variables I need don't exist at this stage! So if I want to run my container command, I would need to expose my env variables to my `settings.py`. Now this completely defeats the purpose of env variables.

Why am I getting this error and is there any way to circumvent this?

Comment: Always makemigrations locally and commit it to git yourself. Then do `eb deploy`. Also you don't need to source venv. Just `python3 manage.py migrate --noinput` should do it.

Comment: Is there any reason why I should run migration locally?

Comment: To keep migrations consistent.

Comment: The OP shouldn’t run `makemigrations` on beanstalk but he/she definitely needs to run `migrate`. The problem remains.

Comment: @VaibhavVishal Why activating virtual environment is not needed? And also using `python manage.py` and `django-admin.py` gives me `ERROR: ServiceError - Failed to deploy the application.` Even if I have the migrations and set the environment as official document suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should define your env vars using ebextensions. 
These are set before container_commands are executed. 
To do it, create a **.config** file with the following lines :

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    FOO: bar
```